# Issues with AnyGantt

Tags: anychart

Im using AnyGantt, but Im having problems setting it up correctly.

Here is the full code:

---

```
var endpoint = '/api/chart/data/'
        var label = []
        var start = []
        var end = []
        var werk = []

        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: endpoint,
            success: function(data){
                labels    = data.label
                start     = data.start
                end       = data.end
                uplant    = data.werk

              var obj = {}
              var finalArray = []
              for (var i = 1; i <= start.length; i++) {
                  var first = { id: i, name: uplant[i] }
                  obj = { ...obj, ...first }
                  var periods = { id: labels[i], start: start[i - 1], end: end[i - 1] }
                  if (obj.periods) {
                      obj.periods.push(periods)
                  } else {
                      obj.periods = [periods]
                  }
                  finalArray.push(obj)
              }

        anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {        
            var data = finalArray;
            var treeData = anychart.data.tree(data, "asTable");
            chart = anychart.ganttResource(); 
            chart.data(treeData);  
            chart.getTimeline().scale().minimum("2018-01-01");
            chart.getTimeline().scale().maximum("2020-01-01");

            var dataGrid = chart.dataGrid();
            dataGrid.column(0)
                .title('#')
                .width(30)
                .cellTextSettings({hAlign: 'center'});
            dataGrid.column(1)
                .title('Werk')
                .width(60)
                .cellTextSettings({hAlign: 'left'})
                .format(function () {
                    return this.name;
                });
            chart.getTimeline().horizontalScrollBar().enabled(true);
            /* chart.getTimeline().periods().edit(true); */
            chart.getTimeline().edit(true);
            chart.getTimeline().tooltip(false);
            chart.getTimeline().elements().labels(false);

            chart.container("containerx");
            chart.draw();
            chart.fitAll();
        });
      },
            error:function(error_data){
                console.log("error")
                console.log(error_data)
            }});
```

---

I can't click and move the periods (tasks) and I cant scroll.

Thank you very much for any suggestions

Please find below a screenshot of the chart:

Please find below a screenshot of the chart:

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Scale range

You are applying the scale min/max correctly:

```
chart.getTimeline().scale().minimum("2018-01-01");
chart.getTimeline().scale().maximum("2020-01-01");
```

But then you override the default scale and it drops the min/max settings:

```
var dateTimeScale = anychart.scales.dateTime();
var dateTimeTicks = dateTimeScale.ticks();
chart.xScale(dateTimeScale);
```

There's no need to do this! The default Gantt Chart is already a dateTime type. Solution - simply remove those three lines above from your code.

---

### LiveEdit

Your line `chart.getTimeline().periods().edit(true);` is correct, but due to a little bug in the current version 8.7.0 (Aug 2019) this setter doesn't work for types of elements. To avoid it replace this line with the following line `chart.getTimeline().edit(true);`.

---

### Scrollers

The Gantt chart doesn't support x/yScrollers, only simple scroll bars. 
The following methods the Gantt chart doesn't support:

```
chart.xScroller(true);
chart.yScroller(true);
```

For zooming, you can use one of the API functions. This subject is described in detail in [the Gantt zooming article](https://docs.anychart.com/Gantt_Chart/Basic_Settings#zooming).

Comment: Now you can't scroll cause you are calling fitAll() method. It zooms out to the full range and the scroll bar gets hidden, there's nowhere to scroll. To enable scrolling you should zoom in a bit. How to zoom you can check in the article I provided in the answer. Editing period should be available. Can you specify the version of the library you are using? Your code works properly in with the current version 8.7.0 - https://playground.anychart.com/vDmnAqLF

Comment: Im using version 8.7.0. I replaced the fitAll() method with chart.zoomIn(3), the scrollbar does show up, but I cant click on it.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? The scrollbar is draggable bar, it doesn't implement any interactivity on a simple click.

Comment: Ive added a screenshot to my post. Can you help?

Comment: Thanks! I see the horizontal scrollbar. It should draggable, does it work? Or do you mean the problem with the vertical scrollbar?

Comment: No, it does not work. As I said, I cant even click on it.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reproduce the issue. Can you provide a sample on AnyCHart Playground or any similar platform where we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Interesting, the scrollbar works in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AndreasBren/rwa3u56b/7/